# MySQL multiple results from one table in one statement

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to use multiple select query in two tables:

Table1 -> infoTab:

```
  theType   |          theTime    | theCount 
------------+---------------------+----------
 WithPinIt  | 2017-04-01 13:00:00 | 45
 WithPinIt  | 2017-04-01 13:00:00 | 100
 WithMinIt  | 2017-04-01 13:00:00 | 75
 WithQinIt  | 2017-05-01 13:00:00 | 45
 WithMinIt  | 2017-06-01 13:00:00 | 55
```

Table2 ->  defsTab:

```
   theId  |   theDefs   |   theType
----------+-------------+-------------
1         |  defQs      |  WithQinIt 
1         |  defOs      |  WithOinIt 
1         |  defJs      |  WithJinIt
```

What I'm trying to get is a result like this:

```
          theTime    |  P  |  M 
---------------------+-----+-----
2017-04-01 13:00:00  | 145 | 
2017-04-01 13:00:00  |     | 75 
2017-06-01 13:00:00  |     | 55
```

So far I used this query:

```
SELECT   
    theTime,   
    (SELECT SUM(theCount) AS pSum FROM infoTab WHERE theType NOT IN (SELECT content FROM defsTab) AND theType LIKE '%P%' GROUP BY theTime) AS Ps,   
    (SELECT SUM(theCount) AS cSum FROM infoTab WHERE theType NOT IN (SELECT content FROM defsTab) AND theType LIKE '%C%' GROUP BY theTime) AS Cs   
FROM infoTab
```

But it does not work... any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should work if you use CASE

```
select
theTime,
sum(
CASE 
WHEN theType like '%P%' THEN theCount
ELSE 0
END) as P,
sum(
CASE 
WHEN theType like '%C%' THEN theCount
ELSE 0
END) as C
from infoTab
where theType NOT IN (SELECT content FROM defsTab)
group by theTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `CASE` statement like this:

```
SELECT 
    theTime, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN theType  LIKE '%P%' THEN theCount ELSE 0 END) AS P,
    SUM( CASE WHEN theType  LIKE '%M%' THEN theCount ELSE 0 END) AS M
FROM infoTab    
WHERE theType NOT IN (SELECT theType FROM defsTab)
group by theTime, theType
```